# Allow a certain bot to access a certain page in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent, bots, referrer

I have .htaccess rules to deny certain bots from accessing a website:

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
...
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I want to allow wget access to a certain page that can have multiple (dynamic) parameters:

```
www.mydomain.com/page.php?pram1=x&param2=y&...
```

How can I allow wget access only to page.php (with parameters ofc) and deny all other pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can add before final `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.php$
# and your last rule
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Don't use `[OR]` for the `RewriteCond` line just before !